# Call function in parent when modal is closed

Tags: react-native

When I close a modal I need to call a function in the parent container. How do I do this?

I'm using a modal as described in the docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html

Comment: You can pass it as a props in modal like this `<MyModal parentFunction={this.imInsideOfParent.bind(this)} />`

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks! If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as such. Is there a reason why sometimes people just post as a comment?

Comment: This kind of questions are frequently asked or easy to solve no need to post an answer.But its just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a callback function in props and invoke it in model's onRequestClose event.